# Error al hacer Update en Sqlite?

Tags: sqlite3

mi problema es que al hacer update a una db sqlite por consola me dice que termino la tarea correctamente pero cuando miro la db sigue sin cambios(aqui intento actualizar los nombres)... pero al finalizar dice que no afecto ninguna fila?

aqui un ejemplo.

```
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Silver' WHERE 'Index' = 1;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Gold Bar 1G' WHERE 'Index' = 2;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Gold Bar 10G' WHERE 'Index' = 3;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Gold Bar 100G' WHERE 'Index' = 4;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Gold Bar 1,000G' WHERE 'Index' = 5;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Pearl' WHERE 'Index' = 6;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Loyalties' WHERE 'Index' = 7;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Gold Bar 10,000G' WHERE 'Index' = 8;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'OBD Labs Gold Bar' WHERE 'Index' = 9;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Pure Black Stone' WHERE 'Index' = 11;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Pure Black Stone' WHERE 'Index' = 12;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Pure Black Stone' WHERE 'Index' = 13;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Pure Black Stone' WHERE 'Index' = 14;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Pure Black Stone' WHERE 'Index' = 15;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Pure Black Stone' WHERE 'Index' = 16;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Pure Black Stone' WHERE 'Index' = 17;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Bartali Gold Bar' WHERE 'Index' = 21;

Ejecución terminada sin errores.
Resultado: consulta ejecutada con éxito. Tardó 0ms, 0 filas afectadas
En la línea 17:
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Bartali Gold Bar' WHERE 'Index' = 21;
```

Comment: Debido a que la BD Sqlite es un archivo físico, verifica que tenga los permisos de escritura correspondientes en el sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías hacer un commit de los cambios para que se apliquen. Podrías hacerlo como una transacción:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Silver' WHERE 'Index' = 1;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Gold Bar 1G' WHERE 'Index' = 2;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Gold Bar 10G' WHERE 'Index' = 3;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Gold Bar 100G' WHERE 'Index' = 4;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Gold Bar 1,000G' WHERE 'Index' = 5;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Pearl' WHERE 'Index' = 6;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Loyalties' WHERE 'Index' = 7;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Gold Bar 10,000G' WHERE 'Index' = 8;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'OBD Labs Gold Bar' WHERE 'Index' = 9;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Pure Black Stone' WHERE 'Index' = 11;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Pure Black Stone' WHERE 'Index' = 12;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Pure Black Stone' WHERE 'Index' = 13;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Pure Black Stone' WHERE 'Index' = 14;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Pure Black Stone' WHERE 'Index' = 15;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Pure Black Stone' WHERE 'Index' = 16;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Pure Black Stone' WHERE 'Index' = 17;
UPDATE 'Item_Table' SET 'ItemName' = 'Bartali Gold Bar' WHERE 'Index' = 21;

COMMIT;
```

Te comparto [este link](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-transaction/) por si queres ampliar.